# Tensorflow memory leak when building graph in a loop

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, memory-leaks

I noticed this when my grid search for selecting hyper-parameters of a Tensorflow (version 1.12.0) model crashed due to explosion in memory consumption.

Notice that unlike similar-looking question here, I do close the graph and session (using context managers), and I am not adding nodes to the graph in the loop.

I suspected that maybe tensorflow maintains global variables that do not get cleared between iterations, so I called globals() before and after an iteration but did not observe any difference in the set of global variable before and after each iteration.

I made a small example that reproduces the problem. I train a simple MNIST classifier in a loop and plot the memory consumed by the process:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import psutil
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

N_REPS = 100
N_ITER = 10
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
x_test, y_test = mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels

# Runs experiment several times.
mem = []
for i in range(N_REPS):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        net = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x_test, 200)
        logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(net, 10, activation_fn=None)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_test, logits=logits))
        train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(loss)
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            # training loop.
            sess.run(init)
            for _ in range(N_ITER):
                sess.run(train_op)
    mem.append(process.memory_info().rss)
plt.plot(range(N_REPS), mem)
```

And the resulting plot looks like this:
[image]

In my actual project, process memory starts from a couple of hundreds MB (depending on dataset size), and goes up to 64 GB until my system run out of memory. There are things that I tried that slow down the increase, such as using placeholders and feed_dicts instead of relying on convert_to_tensor. But the constant increase is still there, only slower.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the graph after each iteration of your for loop before instantiating a new graph. Adding `tf.reset_default_graph()` at the end of your for loop should resolve your memory leak issue.

```
for i in range(N_REPS):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        net = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x_test, 200)
        ...
    mem.append(process.memory_info().rss)
    tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Comment: I know that this and K.clear_session() have been posted around as solutions to this issue, but none of them solved the memory leak in my situation. I have upgraded my tensorflow to 1.13 and I am putting tf.reset_default_graph() and clear_session() after every graph context.

Comment: Having similar issue with 1.15. What solved it for you? @SafooraYousefi

Comment: @OmarShabab maybe try explicit garbage collection inside the loop like stated in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55211315/6246880

Answer (score 0):

Try and take the loop inside the session. Don't create the graph and session for every iteration. Every time the graph is created and variable initialized, you are not redefining the old graph but creating new ones leading to memory leaks. I was facing a similar issue and was able to solve this by taking the loop inside the session.

From [How not program Tensorflow](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/how-not-program-tensorflow-graph.html)

> - Be conscious of when you’re creating ops, and only create the ones you need. Try to keep op creation **distinct** from op execution.
> - Especially if you’re just working with the default graph and running interactively in a regular REPL or a notebook, you can end up with a lot of abandoned ops in your graph. Every time you re-run a notebook cell that defines any graph ops, you aren’t just redefining ops—you’re creating new ones.