# How to force Tensorflow to use tcmalloc-minimal4 for tf.data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-leaks, tensorflow-datasets, ubuntu-20.04

I am coming from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66971031/3864842

Essentially, I am having a memory leak using tf.data and the solution that seems to work for many people, is to use `libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4` instead of the system's memory allocator.

I have installed the library and used it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libtcmalloc-minimal4
LD_PRELOAD="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4" python main.py ...
```

The first run right after the installation worked flawlessly. But after restarting the script, I experienced the leaks again. (same shell, Same script, same command)

Am I doing something wrong? Can I somehow check if Tensorflow/Python is actually using the library?

So far it worked for less than 10% of all test runs (about 50).